# Dynamic number of currying strings

Tags: javascript, currying

I got a question in a job interview that I'm struggling to solve. I need to implement a function that does the following:

```
// func('hello')('world').join(':'); // should output 'hello:world'
// func('hello')('world')('today').join(':'); // should output 'hello:world:today'
// func('hello')('world')('today')('foo').join(':'); // should output 'hello:world:today:foo'
```

The logic needs to support currying with a dynamic number of strings.

So far what I managed to build are these 2 solutions, but they are not fit to the same structure of the wanted function:

The first one will be to invoke the last call, as I can do like that:

```
const prodall = (...a) => { return a.reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, item], []); };
const curry = f => (...a) => a.length ? curry(f.bind(f, ...a)) : f();
const func = curry(prodall);
console.log(func('hello')('world')('today')('foo')().join(':'));
```

The second one fit to my needs, but not with dynamic number of parameters:

```
const curry = (worker, arity = worker.length) => {
    return function (...args) {
        if (args.length >= arity) {
            return worker(...args);
        } else {
            return curry(worker.bind(this, ...args), arity - args.length);
        }
    };
};

let func = curry((a, b, c) => [a, b, c]);
console.log(func('hello')('world')('today').join(':'));
func = curry((a, b, c, d) => [a, b, c, d]);
console.log(func('hello')('world')('today')('foo').join(':'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return functions which all:

- have scope of a persistent array of previous arguments
- return a function object with a `join` property that takes that persistent array and joins it

```js
const func = (arg) => {
  const args = [arg];
  const inner = (arg) => {
    args.push(arg);
    return inner;
  };
  inner.join = () => args.join(':');
  return inner;
};

console.log(func('hello')('world').join(':'));
console.log(func('hello')('world')('today').join(':'));
```